# Spring Actuator RabbitMQ - Prometheus not showing the message count

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring actuator and enabled Prometheus configuration to monitor RabbitMQ message stats but always showing the message count as zero even if there is a message in queue or consumed. IS there any config required to read the message where in case other jvm or cpu usage are properly monitored.

http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus

```
 HELP rabbitmq_rejected_total  
# TYPE rabbitmq_rejected_total counter
rabbitmq_rejected_total{name="rabbit",} 0.0

# HELP rabbitmq_published_total  
# TYPE rabbitmq_published_total counter
rabbitmq_published_total{name="rabbit",} 0.0

# HELP rabbitmq_consumed_total  
# TYPE rabbitmq_consumed_total counter
rabbitmq_consumed_total{name="rabbit",} 0.0
```

Comment: are you running single instance? or multiple replicas? while running multiple replicas this could happen, changing the metrics value in one instance and scraping the metrics from others.

Comment: There is one instance of rabbitmq is running in local and trying to fetch the message count and getting the value as 0. Is there any special config required to monitor or read the message post to queue.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using this [Prometheus Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html) , it runs natively in ErLang runtime and will save you the complexity around configuration and As of 3.8.0, RabbitMQ ships with built-in Prometheus & Grafana support.